# Storing class changes with localStorage - can this be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So I want to create a favourites tag option for each user so have the following code:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
 var didTheyFave = $('.icon-star-empty').click(function() {
   localStorage.setItem('didTheyFave', faveClass());
    alert(localStorage.getItem('didTheyFave'));
 });
}

function faveClass() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "icon-star-empty" );
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'icon-star' );  
 }
```

So, when the empty star icon is clicked it changes to a full icon but want this change to be stored in browser so when they come back it's still the full icon. I tried to invoke a function as the value but don't think that's allowed.

Thanks

Comment: As the name `localStorage` suggest, it is a place do hold data. In your case it is saving the return value of the function. Try to `return 1` in your function and you will see the value saved.

Comment: edited the answer below.

Comment: What are you trying to store in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.localStorage) {
 var didTheyFave = $('#yourIDforStar').click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('icon-star'){
         $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star-empty' ); 
         $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star' );
         var fav = false;
   } else {
          $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star' ); 
         $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star-empty' );
         var fav = true;
   }
   localStorage.setItem('didTheyFave', fav);
    alert(localStorage.getItem('didTheyFave'));
 });
}
```

Try something like this.

Comment: That's great but once the user has clicked I want this to store so if the browser is refreshed it stays as this new .icon-star class?

Comment: Then you need to load your class initially based on what is present in the localStorage. You can do a get before the page load to check if they have `fav` set to true or false, if true set icon-star or else set icon-star-empty.